# I am trying to run a code of research paper and while executing the train.py file i am facing an issue regarding the model input and output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

```
network = networks[str(config[parser_args.task]['NETWORK'])]

for idx, row in grid_df.iterrows(): `
if row['timestamp'] == 'None':
    learning_rate = row['lr']
    spatial_dropout_rate = row['s_d']
    temporal_dropout_rate = row['t_d']
    concat_dropout_rate = row['c_d']
    curr_time_n = datetime.datetime.now()
    curr_time = curr_time_n.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    time_passed_since_start = curr_time_n - start_time_n
    time_passed_since_start_in_min = time_passed_since_start/datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    time_passed_since_start_in_hours = time_passed_since_start_in_min/60

    if time_passed_since_start_in_hours >= 50.:
        #print(f'Not enough time for lr = {}, dropout = {}')
        grid_df.to_csv(grid_file, index=False)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        grid_df.loc[idx, 'timestamp'] = curr_time
        #print(f"Hostname: {socket.gethostname()}, Number of classes = {num_classes}\n Learning              `rate = {learning_rate}\n` dropout rate = {dropout_rate}\n timestamp = {curr_time}") 


        train_generator = crop_generator(input_path=tr_path, batch_size=batch_size, mode="train", do_shuffle=True, epsilon=0)

        val_generator = crop_generator(input_path=val_path, batch_size=batch_size, mode="val", do_shuffle=True, epsilon=0)


        # spatial part starts here
        cnn_base_model = network(include_top=False, weights = 'imagenet',classes=num_classes)

        cnn_output = cnn_base_model.output

        img_avgpool = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_output)

        img_dense_1 = Dense(512, activation="relu")(img_avgpool)

        img_dropout = Dropout(spatial_dropout_rate)(img_dense_1)
        img_dense_2 = Dense(256, activation="relu")(img_dropout)

        # spatial part ends here

        # temporal part starts here
        temporal_input_layer = Input(batch_shape = (None, 23, 1), name='time_input_layer')


        # add an LSTM layer
        lstm_1 = LSTM(100, input_shape=(23,1), dropout=temporal_dropout_rate)(`temporal_input_layer`)

       # lstm_2 = LSTM(64)(lstm_1)
        #x = LSTM(32)(x)

        # add a dense layer
        ts_output = Dense(32, activation="relu")(lstm_1)
        # temporal part ends here

        # add a concatenation layer to combine output of spatial and temporal
        #ts_output.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
        final_merged = concatenate([img_dense_2, ts_output])
        
        # add another dropout 
        concat_dropout = Dropout(concat_dropout_rate)(final_merged)

        # add dense layer
        final_dense = Dense(32, activation="relu")(concat_dropout)


        # and a softmax layer -- num_classes
        predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(final_dense)

        optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0005)

        # this is the model we will train
        model = Model(inputs=[cnn_base_model.input, temporal_input_layer], outputs=predictions)

        
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 

        print(model.summary())
```

My code is attached is above an the error I am facing is the following:(It is the full trace error attached)

```
  File "train-gridsearch.py", line 203, in <module>
    history = model.fit(train_generator,  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1187, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file52u8rjgw.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 232, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 232, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "zero_padding2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)
```

I saw that error is mentioning about the 'zero_padding2d" but I have not seen that the researchers have used that. Can some one help?

Comment: `zero_padding2d` is an internal parameter name to one of the functions you're using. Please show the full traceback error

Comment: Attached the full stack error

Comment: The error is saying your `train_generator` variable is the "wrong size". Also, your error doesn't match code provided. You are missing `model.fit` line, and you never actually use `train_generator` or `val_generator`

Comment: Did you ask the author of the code?

Comment: @OneCricketeer actually i  hid the missing code that you are refering to because it was going to be too long for the question and I think the problem is in the model construction that is why I only showed the Model code.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerMansoor The error message indicates that there is an issue with the input dimensions of a layer named "zero_padding2d". It seems that this layer is not included in the code that you provided.

It's possible that the issue is related to the input shapes of your generators, which are not shown in the provided code. You may want to check that the inputs to the model are compatible with the input shapes of your data.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve]. For example, we don't know what `grid_df` is, and in general, iterating over a dataframe isn't the most optimal solution. Plus, your error may well happen without much of the code in your question

Comment: @EkabaBisong That error is from keras. The line of code causing the problem is at the top of the traceback for `model.fit(train_generator,` (which is also not shown)